# Only one expression can be specified in the select list

Tags: sql, select, join

I need to get this sql query working:

```
SELECT     TOP 15 id, thumb, width, height
FROM         (SELECT     vPictures.id, vPictures.thumb, vPictureCrops.width, vPictureCrops.height
                       FROM          vPictures INNER JOIN
                                              vPictureCrops ON vPictures.id = vPictureCrops.picid
                       WHERE      (vPictureCrops.width = '602') AND (vPictureCrops.height = '131')
                       GROUP BY vPictures.id, vPictures.thumb, vPictureCrops.width, vPictureCrops.height) AS derivedtbl_1
WHERE     (id NOT IN
                          (SELECT     TOP 0 vPictures_1.id, vPictures_1.datetime, vPictures_1.url, vPictures_1.author, vPictures_1.companyID, vPictures_1.source, 
                                                   vPictures_1.people, vPictures_1.text, vPictures_1.thumb, vPictures_1.logo, vPictureCrops_1.id AS Expr1, vPictureCrops_1.picid, 
                                                   vPictureCrops_1.url AS Expr2, vPictureCrops_1.width, vPictureCrops_1.height
                            FROM          vPictures AS vPictures_1 INNER JOIN
                                                   vPictureCrops AS vPictureCrops_1 ON vPictures_1.id = vPictureCrops_1.picid))
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Can you help me?

The error message:
"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS)"

Comment: ...which RDBMS? I'm guessing SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Where (ID not IN(

The Select must only have one field are the IN can not understand which column you are trying to parse.

Eg from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName
FROM Person.Person AS p
    JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS sp
    ON p.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
WHERE p.BusinessEntityID IN
   (SELECT BusinessEntityID
   FROM Sales.SalesPerson
   WHERE SalesQuota > 250000);
GO
```

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the query anyway, can you explain the usage of the where in clause,

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems with `(id NOT IN (SELECT TOP 0 vPictures_1.id, ...`

1. only when column should be specified in the `select` statement after IN. For example `(id NOT IN (SELECT vPictures_1.id FROM ...`
2. even if you make it just one field `vPictures_1.id` the condition will always be false because of `top 0`.